# Incrementing Char Type In Java

Tags: java, char

While practicing Java I randomly came up with this:

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        char x='A';
        x=x+1;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

I thought it will throw an error because we can't add the numeric value `1` to the letter `A` in mathematics, but the following program runs correctly and prints

```
B
```

How is that possible?

Comment: `x` is a char and Unicode value of `'B'` = Unicode value of `'A'` + 1

Comment: You are adding the int to the ASCII code of the char, not to the char itself.

Comment: I wish we can get rid of the term _ASCII_ in the context of Java.  Java has been around since 1995 and has been using Unicode the whole time. #Grumpymorning.

Comment: Try this one `x *= 1.1;` which compiles too. ;)

Comment: The quoted program does not compile. It has two errors, a missing ";", and the need to cast the result of the increment back to char.

Comment: This code will give error about `possible loss of precision`.

Comment: It's showing me error

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In Java, `char` is a numeric type. When you add `1` to a `char`, you get to the next [*unicode code point*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). In case of `'A'`, the next code point is `'B'`:

```
char x='A';
x+=1;
System.out.println(x);
```

Note that you cannot use `x=x+1` because it causes an implicit narrowing conversion. You need to use either `x++` or `x+=1` instead.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about implicit narrowing conversion.

Answer (score 5):

This is the equivalent program of your program:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String args[]){
             char start='\u0041';
             char next='\u0041'+1;
             System.out.println(next);
    }
}
```

But as you see, `next=start+1`, will not work. That's the way java handles.

The reason could be that we may accidentally use `start`, with integer `1` thinking that `start` is an `int` variables and use that expression. Since, java is so strict about minimizing logical errors. They designed it that way I think.

But, when you do, `char next='\u0041'+1;` it's clear that `'\u0041'` is a character and `1` will be implicitly converted into a 2 byte. This no mistake could be done by a programmer. May be that's the reason they have allowed it.

`char` is 2 bytes in java. `char` supports `unicode` characters. When you add or subtract a char var with an offset integer, the equivalent `unicode` character in the unicode table will result. Since, `B` is next to `A`, you got `B`.

Answer (score 5):

A `char` is in fact mapped to an `int`, look at the [Ascii Table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

For example: a capital A corresponds to the decimal number 65. When you are adding 1 to that `char`, you basicly increment the decimal number by 1. So the number becomes 66, which corresponds to the capital B.

Comment: thanks for the link now i understood that java sees char as a number

Answer (score 4):

`char` *is* a numeric type (2 bytes long), and is also the only unsigned numeric primitive type in Java.

You can also do:

```
int foo = 'A';
```

What is special here is that you initialize the `char` with a *character constant* instead of a number. What is also special about it is its string representation, as you could witness. You can use `Character.digit(c, 10)` to get its numeric value (as an `int`, since 2 ^ 16 - 1 is not representable by a `short`!).

Answer (score 4):

you have to type cast the result after adding using parenthesis like this:

```
x='A';
x = (char) (x+1);
```

else you will get loose of data error.

Answer (score 2):

A `char` in Java is just an integer number, so it's ok to increment/decrement it. Each char number has a corresponding value, an *interpretation* of it as a character, by virtue of a conversion table: be it the ASCII encoding, or the UTF-8 encoding, etc.

Come to think of it, every data in a computer - images, music, programs, etc. are just numbers. A simple character is no exception, it's *encoded* or *codified* as a number, too.

Answer (score 2):

`char` are stored as 2 byte unicode values in Java. So if `char x = 'A'`, it means that `A` is stored in the unicode format. And in unicode format, every character is represented as an integer. So when you say `x= x+1`, it actually increments the unicode value of the `A`, which prints `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Because type char effectively works like a 16-bit unsigned int.

So setting `char x='A'` is almost equivalent to `int x=65`  When you add one; you get 66; or ASCII 'B'.

Comment: What?!? Not _one_ byte.  Please check the Java definition.

Comment: It does _not_ work like a 16bit int. `char` is unsigned, `short` is not.

Comment: Thank you for your input to improving the answer.

Comment: @fge +1.  To anyone interested: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Each `char` has a character code. The computer sees a character as an unsigned number, so you can increment it.

Answer (score 0):

in case you want it to be just a-z.

```
private char getNextChar(char c) {
    return (char)((c + 1 - 'a') % ('z' - 'a' + 1) + 'a');
}
```

this avoids it overflows.

Answer (score 0):

In some languages such as Java, the characters are converted into integers based on their ASCII values. Therefore such operations can be performed.

```java
char inp ='A';
inp +=1;
System.out.println(inp);     //Output = B
```