# Why is the char value transforming during the output?

Tags: java

I am making my program to throw a die (as in dices) for a school assignment in Java SE. The user can place a character as standard input, so the character the user picks will represent the eyes of the die. Sometimes when I print the result, it shows a completely different character.

```
package ThrowADie;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThrowADie {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Ask user for the char in which the dices eyes should be printed in.
    System.out.print("Which character should I use for the eye: ");

    //Allow user to place input in the eye variable
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Make the stdinput object
    char eye = input.next().charAt(0);

    //Time to throw the die. Place result in dieResult
    int dieResult = throwDie();

    //Reveal of the result
    printDieResult(dieResult, eye);

}


    /*
    * Method name: throwDie()
    * Purpose: Picks a number from 1 to 6 randomly, like a die does
    * Parameters: N/A
    * Returns: Integer number from 1 to 6    
    */
    public static int throwDie(){
        int range = (6 - 1) + 1;     
        return (int)(Math.random() * range) + 1;
    }


    /*
    * Method name: printDieResult()
    * Purpose: Generate result of the die throw in ASCII art
    * Parameters: numberOfEyes, typeOfEyes
    * Returns: N/A
    */
    public static void printDieResult(int numberOfEyes, char typeOfEyes){
        if (numberOfEyes == 1){
            //Print art
            System.out.println(
                    " " + " " + " \n"
                  + " " + typeOfEyes + " \n"
                  + " " + " " + " ");
        } else if (numberOfEyes == 2){
            //Print art
            System.out.println(
                    typeOfEyes + " " + " \n"
                  + " " + " " + " \n"
                  + " " + " " + typeOfEyes);
        } else if (numberOfEyes == 3){
            //Print art
            System.out.println(
                    typeOfEyes + " " + " \n"
                  + " " + typeOfEyes + " \n"
                  + " " + " " + typeOfEyes);
        } else if (numberOfEyes == 4){
            //Print art
            System.out.println(
                    typeOfEyes + " " + typeOfEyes + "\n"
                  + " " + " " + " \n"
                  + typeOfEyes + " " + typeOfEyes);
        } else if (numberOfEyes == 5){
            //Print art
            System.out.println(
                    typeOfEyes + " " + typeOfEyes + "\n"
                  + " " + typeOfEyes + " \n"
                  + typeOfEyes + " " + typeOfEyes);
        } else {
            //Print art
            //Accidentally written down 9 eye representation
            System.out.println(
                    typeOfEyes + typeOfEyes + typeOfEyes + "\n"
                  + typeOfEyes + typeOfEyes + typeOfEyes + "\n"
                  + typeOfEyes + typeOfEyes + typeOfEyes);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**
This program will generate proper results. But occasionally the char that has been input, that represent the eye of the die, transforms in to a number.

In the case below, the program should print 9 '@' characters. Instead it prints 192 on the first row. (I know dices have 6 eyes but I bumped into this strange output while accidentally printing 9 eyes)

```
run:
Which character should I use for the eyes: @
192
@@@
@@@
```

I can not find the cause of this, can anyone see what I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Character arithmetic!

Consult this [table](http://www.asciitable.com/). `@` is character `64`

`typeOfEyes + typeOfEyes + typeOfEyes + "\n"`

This first line is actually adding up the values of the characters (64 + 64 + 64) = 192, then addending that with a newline, so we get `192\n`.

The compiler is choosing to add those up rather than create a String of characters. The easy way to solve this is to preface that with an empty string in front: `"" + typeOfEyes...`

Basically, the compiler is "dumb." When we add integers to Strings, `"foo" + 123` the compiler can interpret that as `foo123` just fine because it recognizes the first element as a String. However, we've defined a `char` which is a [numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124992/incrementing-char-type-in-java) type representing a character. So the compiler does math with it. Even though we shouldn't be. Adding the String literal tells it we actually want text.

Comment: Essentially, a string is missing from between those summations.

Comment: Wonderful explanation. I feel obliged to say: Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
int test = (int) (typeOfEyes + typeOfEyes + typeOfEyes);

        System.out.println("\n" + test + "\n"
                + typeOfEyes + "" + typeOfEyes + "" + typeOfEyes + "\n"
                + typeOfEyes + "" + typeOfEyes + "" + typeOfEyes + "\n"
                + typeOfEyes + "" + typeOfEyes + "" + typeOfEyes);

Which character should I use for the eye: @

192
@@@
@@@
@@@
```