# Java String Manupulation

Tags: java

Why does the statement below gives error

```
       char rep=(str.charAt(len-1))-1;
       str.replace(str.charAt(len-1),rep);
       error: possible loss of precision
```

when the following code works correctly

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        char x='A';
        x=x+1;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: That code *doesn't* compile correctly: http://ideone.com/00m5mf.

Comment: Got the example from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124992/incrementing-char-type-in-java

Comment: You mean you also coded `error: possible loss of precision` explicitly??

Comment: yeah ..wasn't tht cool @CommuSoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do downcasting(`int --> char`),which is not implicit.You will have to cast it explicitly.

Below code will not compile correctly.

```
        char x='A';
        x=x+1;// can not convert from int to char implicitly.
```

Change it to

```
        char x = 'A';
        x+=1;// it will automatically cast to char(implicit)
```

Similar change your below line of code,you will have to cast it to char.

```
   char rep=(char)((str.charAt(len-1))-1);
```

Comment: "can not convert from char to int" - Yes, you can.

Comment: @xehpuk was a typo actually wanted to say (int to char),Thanks any way

Answer (score 2):

```
char x = 'A';
int temp = x;
temp = temp+1;
x = (char) temp;
System.out.println(x + " " + temp);
```

Try this code because `char` to `int` conversion is implicit but `int` to `char` is explicit conversion.