# Why we can use "for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)"

Tags: java, char

When I want to traverse a-z, I can use:

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    //....
}
```

but what is the inside principle? Why we can compute char and there is no need to transfer to int to compute?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17125003/2318775

Comment: Well, `char` _is_ also a numeric type; a "hybrid" one in the sense that it is used as the basis of anything text, but it is a numeric type.

Comment: Everything in a computer is actually a number.  The fact we have types which are not numbers is just a construct. e.g. `boolean` is actually a number, which in other language (not Java) you can perform maths on as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` is a numeric type, which means that each character has a number assigned to it.

For example, "A" has the value of 65, and "B" has the value of 66. You can find some tables for the first 255 [here](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

Comment: Whether or not you have the permission to repost that image here is dubious.

Comment: @Radiodef Okay. I'll try and find a different image.

Comment: You may consider just changing it to a link. Links are fine as long as it's not the only content in your answer.