# Increment char variable by an int value

Tags: java

I wrote two versions of Java code to increment a char variable by 1:

version1:

```
char c = 'a';
c = c + 1;
```

version2:

```
char c = 'a';
c += 1;
```

To my surprise, the second version compiles and runs successfully but the first one shows an error, which says incompatible types: lossy conversion from int to char. Why are they different?

Answer (score 2):

The second version involves a cast, and is equivalent to:

```
c = (char) (c + 1);
```

See [JLS section 15.26.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) (Compound operators):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

Comment: I've seen someone post questions using the first version, and the code runs too. Why do we get different results?See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124992/incrementing-char-type-in-java

Comment: @Gropai I cannot reproduce that behavior. I get the loss of precision warning in Java9 jShell and Java 8 javac.