# How am I able to increase the index of a char array?

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am trying to count the frequency of words in a String s that consists of only lowercase letters. For as long as I've known how, I do it like this:

```
int[] freq = new int[26];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    freq[s.charAt(i)]++;
}
```

However, I am seeing that this is possible as well:

```
char[] freq = new char[26];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    freq[s.charAt(i)]++;
}
```

How am I able to add 1 to the value of a char array? And when I print out the values of the char array, I am seeing nothing.

Thanks

Comment: This should help with the addition question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124992/incrementing-char-type-in-java

Comment: Please add the code where you print the array values to your question.

Comment: Please also provide a complete, runnable example, as neither of your code samples do what you want.

Comment: Please clarify if you want the frequency of words or letters. Your code seems to be looking for frequency of letters.